# Document interfaces using TypeDoc

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typedoc

I'm using [TypeDoc](https://typedoc.org/guides/doccomments/) to document my TypeScript code just like that:

```js
/**
 * @param timestampValue Date in timestamp format
 */
const getDaysInTimestamp = (timestampValue: number): number => {
  return Math.round(timestampValue / 1000)
}
```

Problem is that I use React functional components like that:

```js
interface Props {
  useLocalStorage?: boolean
  useCookies?: boolean
}

const Application: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  )
}
```

So you can use it like:

```html
<Application useLocalStorage useCookies >
  ...
</Application>
```

But with this structure I'm not able to document the `props` of `Application` in details. Best I can do is this:

```js
/**
 * @param props Props from Application component
 */
const Application: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
  ...
```

I tried using this type of notation but it's not supported:

```js
/**
 * @param props.useLocalStorage Enable the component to store some data in the localStorage
 * @param props.useCookies Enable the component to store and read cookies
 */
const Application: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
  ...
```

So my last chance is to document the interface directly. My question is: Is there a way to write TypeDoc for each attributes of an interface? Maybe something similar to that:

```js
/**
 * @param useLocalStorage Enable the component to store some data in the localStorage
 * @param useCookies Enable the component to store and read cookies
 */
interface Props {
  useLocalStorage?: boolean
  useCookies?: boolean
}
```

Have you any idea how it can be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add type annotations to interfaces similar to how you would for classes.

```
interface Props {
  /** Enable the component to store some data in the localStorage */
  useLocalStorage?: boolean

  /** Enable the component to store and read cookies */
  useCookies?: boolean
}
```

The [`@typeparam`](https://typedoc.org/guides/doccomments/#typeparam-param-name) option is also available for describing generic types however I'm not sure it supports the `Props.useLocalStorage` syntax.

```
/**
 * @typeParam T  Comment for type `T`.
 * You may also use the template tag.
 * @template T comment for type `T`.
 */
function doSomething<T>(target: T, text: string): number;
```